# Unable to decrypt Dart encrypted json in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, encryption, flutter, aes

I have a mobile client developed in Dart, and that is sending requests to a .NET CORE REST API. I need to AES encrypt the credentials the following way: Encrypt user credentials json in Dart using AES, then send the request to the .NET CORE REST API, then decrypt it.

Even though I am using same Key on both side, and same Initialization vector too, I get the following exception on the server side:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is not a complete block.

I am using  .NET CORE 2.2.203, and Dart 2.3.0 .

So this is the encryption on the Dart client side:

```dart
final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('OkREB8tVlnYc0kDmtEE5v33zSP1wP8eB');
final iv = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8('HR92pIjHRe2pIj12');

final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(**asd**, iv: iv);
```

For the string **asd** it generates this:

```
X2C+xO2+aKhoITDNEBCHWg==
```

I am using this decryption in .NET CORE REST API:

```cs
public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            string plaintext = null;
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;

        }
```

And I call it with parameters like this (first parameter is the client side encrypted json)

```cs
DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(
(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("X2C+xO2+aKhoITDNEBCHWg==")),
(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("OkREB8tVlnYc0kDmtEE5v33zSP1wP8eB")),
(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HR92pIjHRe2pIj12"))
);
```

However it is going to crash with this exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is not a complete block.
```

So what I would like to see on the server side is the string **asd**.

Comment: So if you want to *decrypt* data, why are you calling an *encrypt* method? And you want to decrypt what you get back from `Convert.FromBase64String("X2C+xO2+aKhoITDNEBCHWg==")`, not `ASCII.GetBytes()`.

Comment: Sorry, I inserted the wrong code, now I replaced it with the actual method.

Comment: I replaced it with your code, and now i get:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.

Comment: That's probably because you used `Convert.FromBase64` on the other strings, where those should actually use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. First of all, you have to get .NET and Dart to agree on the algorithm. According to the docs, Dart uses AES in SIC (CTR) mode by default, which the .NET implementation does not support (unless you use something like Bouncy Castle). You'd need to change the mode to `AESMode.cbc` to match the .NET defaults.